# bbcode post/template processing with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a post template (`file1`) of a bbcode forum into which I want to insert a file with a description (`fileD`) using sed (I use a file because description can have more than one line and I do not know how to prevent line break being interpreted as `[enter]`. I then save the results in a new file (`file2`) leaving the original one intact.

One of the problems is that `fileD` should be placed between tags `[spoiler] wordtoreplace [/ spoiler]` and I do not know how to do this, since I only found the option to insert a line before or after and that would leave the `wordtoreplace` in place. (I solved that, not very elegantly, by adding few words and then removing them again).

The other problem is that `file1` has tags `[center]...[/ center]`, `[spoiler]...[/ spoiler]` and `[media]...[/ media]` and when moving from one file to another other, it lines containing those tags get removed.

This is the bash that I have (as I said, not very inelegant)

https://pastebin.com/X6qviG7b

```
sed -e "/postsinopsis/r $postsinopsis" -e "x;$G" postbbcode.txt >> "$posttxt".bbcode.txt;
sed -i "s|postimagencabecera|$postimagencabecera|g" "$posttxt".bbcode.txt;
sed -i "s|postimagendescripcion|$postimagendescripcion|g" "$posttxt".bbcode.txt;
sed -i "s|posttrailer|$posttrailer|g" "$posttxt".bbcode.txt;
sed -i "/postdatostecnicos/r $postdatostecnicos" "$posttxt".bbcode.txt;
sed -i "s|postlinkdescarga|$postlinkdescarga|g" "$posttxt".bbcode.txt;
sed -i "s|postaspoiler|[spoiler]|g" "$posttxt".bbcode.txt;
sed -i "s|postspoiler|[/spoiler]|g" "$posttxt".bbcode.txt;
```

input:

```
[center][img]postimagencabecera [/img]
postsinopsis
[img]postimagendescripcion [/img]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=posttrailer
Datos técnicos: postaspoiler
postdatostecnicos
- postspoiler
```

desired output:

```
[center][img]http://imagen.redondito.net/images/2018/04/17/OhTu.md.jpg [/img]
fileD
[img]http://imagen.redondito.net/images/2018/04/17/Ok8z.jpg [/img]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fzmM0AB60QQ
Datos técnicos: [spoiler]
fileD2
- [/spoiler]
```

actual output:

```
[center][img]http://imagen.redondito.net/images/2018/04/17/OhTu.md.jpg [/img]
fileD
postsinopsis
[img]http://imagen.redondito.net/images/2018/04/17/Ok8z.jpg [/img]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fzmM0AB60QQ
Datos técnicos: [spoiler]
fileD2
- [/spoiler]
```

I now get that output, because I added 2 more (sed) calls to the bash script

```
sed -i "s|postaspoiler|[spoiler]|g" "$posttxt".bbcode.txt;
sed -i "s|postspoiler|[/spoiler]|g" "$posttxt".bbcode.txt;
```

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: I edited the original post with the entry, the desired output and the one I get

Comment: You can avoid the line break being interpreted as enter in the console by opening a single or double quote.

Comment: I tried both and it did not work @MadPhysicist